# Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult: not finding any duplicates when they are

Tags: apex, duplicate-management, datacloud

I am stuck when trying to look for a duplicate contact, I am using Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult, however the system is not getting any duplicate so when it tries to save the record I get an:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED

Below is my code on how i am trying to use Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult, but i dont understand what I am missing?

This is result of results (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult[]):

> (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult[getDuplicateResults=(Datacloud.DuplicateResult[getDuplicateRule=Find_Contacts;getDuplicateRuleEntityType=Contact;getErrorMessage=null;getMatchResults=(Datacloud.MatchResult[getEntityType=Contact;getErrors=();getMatchEngine=ExactMatchEngine;getMatchRecords=();getRule=New_Contact_v3;getSize=0;isSuccess=true;]);isAllowSave=false;]);getErrors=();isSuccess=true;])

```
//CHECK DUPLICATE 
Account myAcc = new Account();
Opportunity myOpp = new Opportunity();

List<Contact> myContactList = new List<Contact>();          
Contact myCon = new Contact(
    FirstName = obj.billing_address.first_name,
    LastName = obj.billing_address.last_name,
    Email = obj.email,
    MobilePhone = obj.phone
);

//MANAGE DUPLICATE FOR CONTACT
myContactList.add(myCon);
Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult[] results = Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(myContactList);

for (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult findDupeResult : results) {
    for (Datacloud.DuplicateResult dupeResult : findDupeResult.getDuplicateResults()) {
        for (Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult : dupeResult.getMatchResults()) {
            for (Datacloud.MatchRecord matchRecord : matchResult.getMatchRecords()) {
                if (matchRecord.getMatchConfidence() >= 90) {
                    myCon = (Contact)matchRecord.getRecord();
                    myAcc = myCon.Account;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

myCon.MailingStreet = obj.billing_address.address1;
myCon.MailingCity = obj.billing_address.city;
myCon.MailingState = obj.billing_address.province_code;
myCon.MailingCountry = obj.billing_address.country;
myCon.MailingPostalCode = obj.billing_address.zip;
if (myCon.Id == null) {
    myCon.AccountId = myAcc.Id;
    insert myCon;
} else {
    update myCon;
}
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found what was going on, my duplicate rule use 5 fields

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Email
4. Mobile
5. Mailing Zip/Postal Code

When I created the contact to find the duplicate i didnt have the mailing zip:

```
List<Contact> myContactList = new List<Contact>();          
Contact myCon = new Contact(
    FirstName = obj.billing_address.first_name,
    LastName = obj.billing_address.last_name,
    Email = obj.email,
    MobilePhone = obj.phone
);
```

So I just added

`MailingPostalCode = obj.billing_address.zip,`

And thats fixed